# %23 in color code not decoding

Tags: android

I'm loading some html into a webview using `loadData()`.  Per the documentation I've html encoded the `#s` in the markup as `%23`, e.g. `<div style="color:%23ffffff">`.

The color isn't being set, though. I don't have the option of using named colors, e.g. white, since the markup is being generated by other individuals and they need precise control over colors.

I also tried `loadDataWithBaseURL()` and it exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: Where is it documented that you should escape `#` in HTML attributes? Just don't do that and it will work.

Comment: public void loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)


The encoding parameter specifies whether the data is base64 or URL encoded. If the data is base64 encoded, the value of the encoding parameter must be 'base64'. For all other values of the parameter, including null, it is assumed that the data uses ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and use the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. For example, '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f respectively.

Comment: What happens if you ignore the javadoc and not encode `#` as `%23`?